# Convert curl command to PHP for csv->Excel converter

Tags: php, curl

Looks simple enough, but I can't get this to work in PHP.

```
curl -F files[]=@myfile.csv 'https://www.rebasedata.com/api/v1/convert?outputFormat=xlsx&errorResponse=zip' -o output.zip
```

myfile.csv is my data file to convert.

output.zip is the response containing the Excel file.

It's a csv to Excel converter service from this website https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-csv-to-excel-online

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
set_time_limit(0);

// output file
$fp = fopen('output.zip', 'w+');

$ch = curl_init('https://www.rebasedata.com/api/v1/convert?outputFormat=xlsx&errorResponse=zip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Adding file to request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['files' => curl_file_create('myfile.csv')]);
// For returning response data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
fwrite($fp, $data);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you, Nikita, but it's not working. I'm running that code from xampp, and also tried it on a webhost. It creates the output.zip but it is an empty zip file.

Comment: Still not working. Now instead of a 0 byte file that opens it creates a 26 byte file that will not open. Says "it is an invalid zip file"

Comment: Thank you Nikita. I appreciate the help.